# Ubuntu 16.04 has taken over iMac - was dual-boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, macosx

I've been unable to find this problem anywhere and hope someone can help.
I did a dual install of Ubuntu 16.04 and OS X El Capitan on an 2009 iMac (9,1). I installed rEFInd, too. rEFInd showed up twice then disappeared. After that Ubuntu would boot automatically unless I pressed OPTION and chose OS X. Then that broke and I've only been able to boot into Ubuntu. I can't boot from a reliable back-up of the OS X partition or reliable Ubuntu live USB. I've tried booting and pressing right Shift, left Shift, esc. None work. My iMac is trapped in Ubuntu! I've found some instructions to make changes in /etc/grub.d/40_custom and have tried a few but they haven't worked either.

Ubuntu seems to work just fine. I just want to be able to get into OS X, too.

If anyone has any idea of how to fix this I would be very grateful! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you're in Ubuntu have you tried opening a terminal and typing:

```
sudo update-grub
```

and then rebooting?

Comment: Yes, more than once.

Answer (score 0):

When I run `sudo update-grub`this is the response

```
$ sudo update-grub
[sudo] password for debdrex: 
Generating grub configuration file ...
Warning: Setting GRUB_TIMEOUT to a non-zero value when GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT is set is no longer supported.
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-36-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-36-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-4.13.0-32-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-4.13.0-32-generic
done
```

Is the GRUB-TIMEOUT statement an issue?
Also, when I reboot I never see a GRUB menu - the screen is dark and then I get the purple Ubuntu splash screen.